# Deserialize text in Java data structure

Tags: java, deserialization

I would like to `eval()` the following text:

```
(2, [(3, 4), (5, 6)])
```

in Java, into some objects I defined, so let's assume:

```
new Pair(1, new ArrayList<Pair>({new Pair(3,4), new Pair(5,6)}))
```

What is the strategy to achieve so? The idea is that I could get any of the following:

```
(2, [(3, 4), (5, 6), (5, 6)])
(2, [(3, 4), (5, 6)])
(2, [(3, 4)])
```

Should I match it with regular expressions?

This is my attempt:

```
/\(([0-9]+), \[(?:\(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\)(?:, )?)+\]\)/
```

Comment: Can you have arbitrary nesting? e.g. `((((((((1, 2))))))))`.

Comment: nope, only the examples I have shown

Comment: Have you consider using JSON format? it's almost identical on what you are doing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be what you are looking for. Sorry still a bit new at formatting.

```
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test[] = {"(2, [(3, 4), (5, 6), (5, 6)])",
            "(7, [(3, 4), (5, 6)])",
            "(10, [(3, 4)])"
    };

    // clean string
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        test[i] = test[i].replace("(", "")
                .replace("[", "")
                .replace(")", "")
                .replace("]", "")
                .replace(" ", "");
    }

    List<Pair> pairList = new ArrayList();

    for (String s : test){
        String[] tmpStrArr = s.split(",");
        List<Pair> tmpLst = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        int index = Integer.parseInt(tmpStrArr[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < tmpStrArr.length; i += 2){
            tmpLst.add(new Pair(index, new Pair(tmpStrArr[i], tmpStrArr[i + 1])));
        }

        pairList.addAll(tmpLst);
    }

    // just here for break point
    System.out.println();
}
```